# Columns not recognized when importing HDF5 file

Tags: python, pandas, hdf5, vaex

I am trying to import an `HDF5` file in python. I do not have details how the file was written. Therefore, I tried `vaex` and `pandas` to open it. How can I specify my columns, so that they are recognized?

I tried to check the structure of the file with:

```bash
$ h5ls -v file.hdf5/DataSet
Opened "file.hdf5" with sec2 driver.
DataSet                  Dataset {5026/Inf}
    Attribute: Species scalar
        Type:      12-byte null-terminated ASCII string
    Attribute: Tuning scalar
        Type:      8-byte null-terminated ASCII string
    Location:  1:800
    Links:     1
    Chunks:    {1} 88 bytes
    Storage:   442288 logical bytes, 442288 allocated bytes, 100.00% utilization
    Type:      struct {
                   "Scan"             +0    native double
                   "col6"            +8    native double
                   "col5"            +16   native double
                   "col10"           +24   native double
                   "col7"            +32   native double
                   "col8"            +40   native double
                   "col1"            +48   native double
                   "col2"            +56   native double
                   "col4"            +64   native double
                   "col9"            +72   native double
                   "col3"            +80   native double
               } 88 bytes
```

## vaex

When I am using `vaex`, the individual columns are not recognized and all the data ends up in a single column `DataSet`.

```py
import vaex as vx
df = vx.open('file.hdf5')
df
df['DataSet']
```

The output looks like this:

```
#      DataSet
0      '(0., 1.36110629e-11, 5.45816316e-09, 3.79845801...
1      '(1., 1.3613447e-11, 5.45889204e-09, 3.79879826e...
...
```

```
Expression = DataSet
Length: 5,026 dtype: [('Scan', '<f8'), ('col6', '<f8'), ('col5', '<f8'), ('col10', '<f8'), ('col7', '<f8'), ('col8', '<f8'), ('col1', '<f8'), ('col2', '<f8'), ('col4', '<f8'), ('col9', '<f8'), ('col3', '<f8')] (column)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   0  '(0., 1.36110629e-11, 5.45816316e-09, 3.79845801...
   1  '(1., 1.3613447e-11, 5.45889204e-09, 3.79879826e...
...
```

Is there an option/way to tell `vx.open` how my columns are organized?

## pandas

I tried to import the file using `pandas` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59347537/6541861), but

```py
pd.read_hdf('file.hdf5')
```

results in an `ValueError`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the `h5py` package to read the `HDF5` file and the `vaex.from_array` method to create a dataframe.

```py
import vaex
import h5py

with h5py.File('file.hdf5', 'r') as data_file :
    dset = data_file['DataSet']
    df = vaex.from_arrays(Scan = dset['Scan'], col1 = dset['col1'], col2 = dset['col2'], col3 = dset['col3'], col4 = dset['col4'], col5 = dset['col5'], col6 = dset['col6'], col7 = dset['col7'], col8 = dset['col8'], col9 = dset['col9'], col10 = dset['col10'])
df
```